# jQuery Mobile Tabs not showing all content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-tabs

The third tab is not showing any content but the first two work fine. Not sure what is wrong as I am following this example from the jQuery website. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/tabs/

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <title>Social</title>
</head>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    collapsible: true, active: false
    });
  });
</script>

<body>

<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">

  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three" data-ajax="false">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

    <div id="one" style="display:none;">
        <p> content one </p>
    </div>

    <div id="two" style="display:none;">
        <p> content two </p>  
    </div>

    <div id="three" style="display:none;">
        <p> content three </p>
    </div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/qx6g1u0x/

Comment: use $(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageid", function(){... instead of $(function() {... http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LkL1o1hu/

Comment: @ezanker delegation is not an issue here, the html elements are already loaded on DOM ready.

Comment: I still can't see third tab content when I test in my browser. (tested in safari, chrome, and firefox) Any reason for this?

Comment: @SterlingArcher, it is not about delegation, it is about using jQuery Mobile's events to ensure that the tabs widget has been initialized before running the code.

Comment: @Jon, can you make one of our jsFiddles reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ezanker, the jsfiddle works fine in my browser. When I open the HTML file from my computer, there is still a problem.

Comment: @Jon, did you try adding a jQM data-role="page" dive around your tabs like in my fiddle?

Comment: @ezanker, Yes, still nothing.